# Fail to load heapsnapshot

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to to analyze my node.js memory leak using V8 heapsnapshot and Chrome Developer Tool.

Unfortunately, dev tool always crash at "Building postorder index...".
The heapsnapshot files are between 70mb and 620mb.

Any other way to analyze the memory heap file?
What can I do to find out the cause of the crash?